# How can we read other UserIds Health Data from Google Fit API

Tags: google-fit

With Google fit API how do we read Health and Location Data of other users?

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/{userId}/dataSources/{dataSourceId}/datasets/{datasetId}
```

So how can we replace userId and instead of me read dataSources and DataSets for other gmail users who are on Google Fit?

I was reading online that other users need to grant the OAuth token to me, before i can read their data, so how is that possible? are there any steps to get oAuth token from other users?

Basically i am trying to read Data of Multiple Users at the same time.